# Grunt build - delete non min files

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using grunt to create my build files.

I have a folder called build, I'm using clean to delete the files in build and then copying the files 
from source folder to the build folder and then minifying the css and javascript.

This way still, has the non minified css and javascript.

How do I copy just the minified files or delete the non minified from the build folder.

```js
clean:{
    build:{
        src: ['build'],
    }
},

copy:{
    build:{
        cwd: 'source',
        src:['**'],
        dest:'build',
        expand:true
    },
},

cssmin : {
    css:{
        src: 'build/css/styles.css',
    dest: 'build/css/styles.min.css'
    }
},

uglify : {
    js: {
    files: {
        'build/js/base.min.js' : [ 'build/js/base.js' ]
    }
  }
}

grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean','copy','cssmin','uglify']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just build directly to the `build/` folder from the `source/` with the cssmin/uglify tasks. Then you don't need the copy/clean tasks.

```
cssmin : {
  css:{
    src: 'source/css/styles.css',
    dest: 'build/css/styles.min.css'
  }
},
uglify : {
  js: {
    src: ['source/js/base.js'],
    dest: 'build/js/base.min.js'
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, that's great but I still need the copy to copy the rest of the folders and files into the build folder. I want to copy the all the files from source to build part from the non minified files.